# JDBC encoding to sql server smalldatetime

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, smalldatetime

I'm trying to execute a stored proc where one of the parameters is of type `smalldatetime`.  In the past I've always encoded `datetime2` and `datetime` fields as strings and that worked fine.  I'm using the [Microsoft JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)

I am getting this error when trying to use a string/nvarchar for the smalldatetime parameter.

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to smalldatetime. Query: EXEC dg.FooBar ?, ?, ?, ?, ? Parameters: [[123, 1, 2099-01-01, 1, DG TEST]]
```

Looking at the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types) it suggests using the `java.sql.Timestamp` class.  Changing my java code to `Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2099, 1, 1).atStartOfDay())` I get a similar error.

```
Error converting data type datetime2 to smalldatetime. Query: EXEC dg.FooBar ?, ?, ?, ?, ? Parameters: [[123, 1, 2099-01-01 00:00:00.0, 1, DG TEST]]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date range supported by smalldatetime is 1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql

You are attempting to pass 2099-01-01 00:00:00.0, which is out of range.

Comment: Ah *smacks head* - I head read elsewhere on SO that the maximum year was 9999, but didn't think to double check that. Thanks!